# split text if contains certain string postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, regexp-replace

```
exit_reason

sr_inefficient_management
tech_too_complex
company_member_resignation
sr_product_engagement
sr_contractual_reasons
sr_contractual_reasons-expectation_issues
sr_churn-takeover_business
```

I would like to split the column if the value contains the string "sr_" and keep the rest as it is. If the column contains "-" such as "sr_contractual_reasons-expectation_issues", I only want to keep it as "contractual reasons".
So far, my idea is to use

```
case when exit_reason like '%inefficient_management%' then 'inefficient management'
```

but if there are many different values, I am in trouble.

Expected output

```
exit_reason column

tech too complex
company member resignation
product engagement
contractual reasons
contractual reasons
churn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace `'sr_'`

```
replace(exit_reason, 'sr_', '')
```

It is unlikely that `'sr_'` would appear in any of the reasons.  But you can use `regexp_replace()` to be sure:

```
regexp_replace(exit_reason, '^sr_', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like it:

```
REPLACE(
    CASE
        WHEN exit_reason LIKE '%-%'
        THEN split_part(exit_reason,'-',2)
        WHEN exit_reason LIKE 'sr_%'
        THEN split_part(exit_reason,'sr_',2)
        ELSE exit_reason
    END
    , '_', ' '
)
```

This code first checks if 'exist_reason' has a hyphen, then if it has 'sr_' and replaces all underscores with blanks.

Answer (score 0):

To also remove the suffix, you could use:

```
SELECT replace(
          regexp_replace(
             'sr_contractual_reasons-expectation_issues',
             '^(sr_)?([^-]*).*$',
             '\2'
          ),
          '_',
          ' '
       );

       replace       
═════════════════════
 contractual reasons
(1 row)
```

The regular expression matches an optional leading `sr_`, then all characters until the first `-`, then anything that follows that, and keeps only the middle part. `replace` then replaces underscores with spaces.